# isomorphism between the coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying affine algebraic varieties(or also called closed sets). I'm using the book of Shafarevich. Let's assume that $k=\overline{k}$

There is a proposition that said:

Let $X,Y$ be two closed sets in the affine space $k^n$ , then:

$X,Y$ are isomorphic (i.e there exist a regular map , with a inverse regular map) if and only if:

$K[X],K[Y]$ (they coordinate rings) are isomorphic as k-algebras.

I only proved the first side ( $X,Y$ isomorphic $\Rightarrow$ $K[X],K[Y]$ isomorphic

Comment: Do you know that there is a natural bijection between regular maps $X \to Y$ and algebra homomorphisms $k[Y] \to k[X]$?

Comment: @Daniel : What do you want to ask ? Please make it precisely. I guess that you want to prove the reverse : If the coordinate rings $K[X], K[Y]$ are isomorphic, then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic ?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh Yes man! exactly that :D!